# Backbone.history.start issue? root param produce no effect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm trying to change default root through backbone.history.start

So, i'm starting with:

router.js

```
router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
  '' : 'home'
  },
  home:function(){
       console.log("home");
  }
});
```

app.js

```
var app = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) 
    {
      var AppRouter = new router();
      Backbone.history.start({pushState: true,root: "/home"});
    }
});
```

So, after this example, if i trigger

```
mydomain.com/
```

will fire up "home"

My main page is entirely served by server side.
ie:

```
mydomain.com/
```

after successful login, user is redirected to mydomain.com/home which should be prepared and render by client side.

So, i just want set my root to mydomain/home and not mydomain/ which is default to backbone.history.start

am i missing something?

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true,root: "/home"})
```

fired up always in this two cases

Comment: Have you tried 'home/' ?

Comment: 'home/' as root? must be '/home#something'..